# Loop through row child elements of multiple tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this sample http://jsfiddle.net/7aDak/927/ . I need to iterate through each table's each row's dropdown and textarea and build a string based on that . I must not use id's . How would  I do it ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was almost set.. just needed minor fix.. See below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7aDak/931/

```
$("#btnSave").click(function() {

    $(".templateTable").each(function() {
        //v-- Used $(this).find('tr') to get all tr from the selected table
        $(this).find("tr").each(function() {
            $this = $(this)
            var email = $this.find("textarea").val();
            var frequency = $this.find("select").val();
            alert(email + '--' + frequency);
        });
    });
});
```

or As suggested by [Rune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396022/jquery-loop-through-row-child-elements-of-multiple-tables/12396078#comment16656544_12396078)

```
$("#btnSave").click(function() {
    $(".templateTable tr").each(function() {
        $this = $(this)
        var email = $this.find("textarea").val();
        var frequency = $this.find("select").val();
        alert(email + '--' + frequency);
    });
});
```

Comment: The second `each` is not necessary, you can use `.templateTable tr` for that. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7aDak/933/). This will save alot of unneeded data.

Answer (score 0):

`this "tr.item"` is not a real selector.

You need to split them into two separate chained selections:

```
$(this).find("tr.item")
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/7aDak/935/

change in html: you need to add a class 'select' to all your select elements. 
Rest is in js code.